# How to connect to an HTTPS WebDAV Folder on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, https, webdav, connection

I'm trying to connect to an HTTPS WebDAV folder on Windows 7.  I go to a "Computer" Explorer window, right click, and click "Add a Network Location."  I follow the prompts and get "The folder you entered does not appear to be valid.  Please choose another."  It works fine on Windows XP.  How do I make this work?

Comment: Did you create a second account to answer this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of going through the GUI it said you should go to a command prompt and type in a command similar to this one:

net use * https://webdav.example.com:port/folder

It prompted me for a username and password and then mapped the drive.

I was able to access my files this way. Hope it works for you.

-[Source](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=164&t=28693#p131915)

Comment: Should that be `net use * https://webdav.example.com:port/folder *`?  According to the docs, the second `*` means it should prompt for a password.

Answer (score 4):

This works for Windows 10:

```
net use drive_letter: \\sitename@ssl@port/folder/subfolder password /user:userID
```

The `@port` is the port number if required. For example

```
net use x: \\webdav.example.edu@ssl@5050/proj/xyz correct.horse.battery.staple /user:stu
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The best answer here. I wonder why it doesn't work with GUI...

Comment: This one worked, but I also had to start a service called `WebClient`. I set it to `Automatic`, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Go to a "Computer" Explorer window, right click, and click "Add a Network Location.

In the dialog box you write like this

```
\\yourserverfqdn@SSL\folder
```

for example if your webdav URL is https://www.netshahr.com/tech  should be

```
\\www.netshahr.com@SSL\tech
```

Notes:

Don't add 'https://' at start of you address

Your SSL certificate should be added to windows store if it is self signed.

Sometimes it fails at first time but with second try it works .

Comment: Now, how does get the certificate and add it to the store?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Webclient service is not running on windows 8.1+ client. But for windows 7 client this service is running by default.

So please try to start the WebClient service on windows 8.1+ client to check if it helps.

I just got it working by doing this =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mklink` in `Windows 7`+

```
mklink /J "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\RemoteResourceName" \\remoteserver.com.pl@SSL@2078\DavWWWRoot
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got it going with a combination of the answers above, so I am posting it here for future reference.

In a Windows 10:

Enable WebClient Service, and use the below command:

*For context, the address used is for a webdav address in Nextcloud.
All uppercase letters should be changed accordingly*

```
net use X: https://WEBDAV.DOMAIN.ADDRESS/remote.php/dav/files/USERNAME/  PASSWORD /user:USERNAME
```