# How to access WebDAV using Windows Explorer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, webdav, cpanel

Using cPanel on my shared web hosting account, I set up a WebDAV directory and account.

But neither the Wizard-based *"Add a network location"*, nor the [net use](https://superuser.com/a/254114/164116) approach result in any successful connection: They both basically say that they were not able to authenticate the user.

Is there a systematic, methodical step-by-step recipe to make this work on Windows 7 (64-bit)?

(connecting to the same WebDAV from Windows XP works fine)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows Explorer Address Bar supports URI's in the following format:

`\\server@SSL@port\DavWWWRoot\path\`

Leave off the @SSL if you are not using SSL/HTTPS.

Leave off the @port part unless you are using a non-default port, example:

`\\server@233\DavWWWRoot\path\`

to not use SSL and use non-default port 233.

So...

Click Start menu...

Click Documents... (or Pictures or any other link that opens explorer.exe)

On the top of the window, there is an address bar that will say something like
JohnSmith\Documents

Change that to the above-mentioned WebDAV format URI and press enter... (Probably something simple like `\\website-with-webdav\davwwwroot\path\`, edit this to get the correct path.)

You could then create a shortcut to that folder to open it faster.

source: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows

Answer (score 1):

windows 10 and 2017 ... try

```
\\yourdomain.com\your_web_dav_root
```

backslashes(!)

nothing else needed and ...

nothing else seems to work ...  no http(s)://foobar or alike (seems to still not working)