# How to connect FTP/WebDav folder as virtual drive in W7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, webdav

I need to connect a remote folder on a laptop with W7 Pro 64bit. My sister got a login information in following format:

host: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX

login: uzivatel

password: HESLO

She was advised to use Total Commander (TC) to set a ftp connection and only uncheck "use passive mode" for the transfer. TC works but is not much user friendly for her.

We currently use [Bitkinex](http://www.bitkinex.com/) which works and the GUI is better but adding the folder as a new drive directly to Windows Explorer would be much better. Tried NetDrive but cannot connect - if I set ftp - port 21 is automatically chosen, if WebDav - port is 80 buth in both cases get error "login failed".

Here is [complete log from BitKinex](http://sharetext.org/DNfN) which might help. I tried to post it here, but this website somehow damages the code...

I would appreciate any advice how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to an HTTPS WebDAV Folder on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/254113/how-to-connect-to-an-https-webdav-folder-on-windows-7), [How to access WebDAV using Windows Explorer on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/494203/how-to-access-webdav-using-windows-explorer-on-windows-7?lq=1)